# Is there (fast) fourier transform for vector convolution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Given a list of variables $u_1,\dots,u_m\in\mathbb R$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb R$ the standard convolution is defined

$$U*V(t)={\sum_{i}} u_iv_{t-i}.$$

Given a list of vectors $u_1,\dots,u_m\in\mathbb R^d$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb R^d$ define vector-convolution $$U*V(t)={\sum_{i}}u_iv_{t-i}^T.$$

> 1. Is there a Fourier transform for this convolutions that converts this to a 'product' $\widetilde U(f)\cdot\widetilde V(f)$ from which we can perform inverse fourier transform to get the convolution?
> 2. Can we replace $u_iv_{t-i}^T$ by a polynomial or a rational function with $u_i,v_i\in\mathbb R^d$ arguments ($2d$ variables)?

Do these admit $FFT$`s?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Could you please specify what kind of an object $U * V$ is? Seems like $U*V(t)$ is a sum of numbers, so is $U*V$ a list of numbers? Also, if $n\not= m$, what is the sum over?

Comment: @DmitryKrachun Capitalization refers to vector of vector variables. Convolution is a vector and the `Fourier` transforms are not invertible here.

Comment: Can't you just take Fourier transform component-wise?

Comment: Perhaps no speed up is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think this all falls out of general nonsense with group algebras.  Given a locally compact group $G$ there is a homomorphism of Banach algebras $\mathcal{F} \colon L^1(G) \to C_0(\hat{G})$ where:

- $L^1(G)$ is the space of integrable functions with respect to Haar measure
- The Banach algebra structure on $L^1(G)$ is given by convolution
- $\hat{G} = \text{Hom}(G, S^1)$ is the Pontryagin dual of $G$

This map $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform that you're looking for, where $G$ is just the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$.  (I'm viewing $U$ and $V$ as compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{Z}$, which certainly are in $L^1(\mathbb{Z})$.)  The fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a homomorphism of Banach algebras means it carries convolution to multiplication, and the Pontryagin duality theorem says that there is an inverse Fourier transform which implements the isomorphism between $G$ and its double dual.

You can extract the details from a representation theory textbook, but unwinding the definitions the formula you get for $\mathcal{F}$ is:

$$\mathcal{F}U(t) = \sum_j u_j e^{-2 \pi i j t}$$

(Well, you might get slightly different formulas depending on your conventions for writing down the Haar measure.)

Comment: Oops, my answer only explicitly addresses the case where the $u_j$'s and $v_j$'s are in $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^d$.  There is a "vector valued" version of the Gelfand transform / Pontryagin duality; I can try to dig up a reference if needed.

Comment: would vector valued nonsense also admit fft?

Comment: @Turbo The DFT (and therefore the FFT) lives on the group $G = \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$, so I'm not sure how to reconcile that with the definition of convolution that you gave in the question - normally the notion of convolution which is compatible with the DFT is the so-called "circle convolution", which requires that $U$ and $V$ have the same number of components so that they can be periodically extended.  I'm not immediately sure whether the FFT extends to that notion of vector-valued DFT, but it would be sort of weird if it didn't.

Comment: Hadamard Product of Fourier transform of two vectors is Fourier transform of convolution of the two vectors. We can interpret $u_i,v_j\in\mathbb R^d$ as fourier transform of convolution of inverse fourier transform of $u_i,v_j$ and the inner product is sum of the elements of the fourier transform and it might be possible to relegate the summation operation needed for inner product as a special operation in the end. Perhaps there is a different way to look at things.